# cshtml load time issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm investigating the perf issue...
I have log statement just before View("Index",Model) call to capture the time/latency information.
when i compare this log entry timestamp with the IIS log, there is always difference of few seconds.
It means, its taking time during the View.

What are different pointers to debug this issue?

cshtml is not making any server call but just iterating over loop from model data (30 count) and showing 1-2 line of information for each.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Can you try again, perhaps with some code?

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by having multiple view engines configured for your application. By default, ASP.NET MVC loads both `WebFormViewEngine` and `RazorViewEngine` with `WebFormViewEngine` taking priority. So, ASP first searches your directory structure views for `WebFormsViewEngine` and if it doesn't find any. then goes on to search with `RazorViewEngine`. Of course if you aren't using any web forms for views, this is inefficient. You can disable by running this code in your applications bootstrap (e.g. global.asax)

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```